# How to plot tropical varieties?

Tags: tropical-geometry

I'm reading "*Introduction to Tropical Geometry*" by Maclagan and Sturmfels and wanted to do some plotting myself of different tropical varieties in both 2D and 3D. On my computer, I have installed Polymake and SAGE (which should contain Gfan). I have tried reading the documentation for both programs but find them hard to follow. Does anyone have a more elaborate guide to plotting tropical varieties or maybe some examples of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two references, which contains guides and examples in Polymake:

- Appendix C in *Essentials of Tropical Combinatorics* by Michael Joswig.
- *Tropical Computations in Polymake* by Simon Hampe and Michael Joswig.